# Clear a NSDictionary of NSarrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I spent a lot of time trying hundreds of things, and searching on the internet for my problem, but I didn't find anythig, so I hope you guys will be able to help me :).

So, I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that I populate with `NSArrays` when I parse an XML document. My problem is, I want to empty it before I release it because it appears to cause leaks !

Best solution, to my eyes, is : `[myDict removeObjectsForKeys : [myDict allKeys]]` but the app crashes and I get the following message in the console :

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'`

I really can't figure why... any ideas ?

EDIT

Important point I forgot  (I guess...), is that the dictionary I'm calling is in my application Delegate, with `appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];`. (appDelegate defined in my .h with myAppDelegate class type).

Then, I initialize it like this : `appDelegate.myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Is it wrong ?

What's weird then, is that when I do :

```
    [appDelegate.myDict release];
    NSLog( @"%@", appDelegate.myDict);
```

I get the dictionary filled...

EDIT 2

I just figured out that all my appDelegate variables are not released when I call `[appDelegate.myVariable release]` ... Wtf am I doing wrong ? This is driving me crazy ><

Comment: did you allocated your dictionary statically ?

Answer (score 3):

When you release a dictionary or array it releases all the elements inside it.  If you're getting leaks they're not due to a failure to remove the objects.

Of course, in your case part of your problem appears to be that you don't know where the error is occurring.  `-[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)` indicates that you were executing `objectAtIndex` on an (empty) `NSArray`, and that doesn't happen (directly) if you do `[myDict removeObjectsForKeys : [myDict allKeys]]` on an NSDictionary.  So you need to figure out where that error is really coming from.

Comment: I read everywhere thant when you release a dictionary it releases everything in it. I'm using an XMLParser, and when I use it more than 1 time I got leaks with another array (of strings). I tryed to clear it by releasing the objects in it, no more leaks... Btw, I'll search for where the error is occuring.

Comment: Trust me -- the problem is not with the dictionary.  Whatever you tried that "fixed" either didn't really, or it fixed some other problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
// myDict should be NSMutableDictionary
[myDict removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: You should search the problem in objects that are stored in your `myDict`. Try to check first of all your arrays, may be they were released somewhere?

Comment: I tried to log them with NSLog and yes, they are still there when I whant to delete them from `myDict`

Comment: NSDictionary does not have "removeAllObjects" method

Comment: @sudip we are not talking about `NSDictionary`, we are talking about `NSMutableDictionary`. So your `-1` is wrong.

Comment: @Nekto So sorry. The title of the question says "Clear NSDictionary ..." but the question content is related to NSMutableDictionary. I am trying to revert the -1, but the system say unless you make some changes to the answer, I cant vote again. Anyway, I am sorry to vote down.

Comment: @sudip No worries, just wanted to metion. Anyway added comment to my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This should hep you figure out which key (or keys) are pointing to the misbehaving arrays.

```
 for ( NSString *key in [myDict allKeys]) {
      NSLog(@" key - %@", key);
      [myDict removeObjectForKey: key];
 }
 NSLog(@" the problem is not with the dictionary...");
```

Comment: Edit I see also the NSLog after that says "the problem is not with the dictionary, but whatever I try to do after, it crashes and a get the error message :/

Comment: How is myDict declared?  Do you set up a /@property and /@synthesize it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to empty an `NSMutableDictionary` before releasing. Any objects retained by the dictionary will sent a `release` message when the dictionary is `dealloc`ed.

It sounds as though your arrays are being retained elsewhere, causing the leak. Are you sure you've implemented `dealloc` methods correctly for all your objects (view controllers, model objects, etc)?

Comment: Everything seems ok :/ when I run my app without filing it, I don't get any leaks, that's why I suspected it to be the source of the leak.

Comment: Could the object you're using to parse the XML be retaining the arrays, but isn't being `dealloc`ed itself (so not releasing them)? Or maybe your parser's dealloc isn't releasing all the objects it should.